# How does one use the "with" statement on a "Where" clause via the REST API?

Tags: where-clause, versionone

I am harvesting stories that do not have a new asset we added populated. I do not wish to see all such stories possible, but only the stories that belong to 9 specific programs. I was pointed to using the "with" selector in the "where" clause. This however is not limiting the results returned to only provide the ones that are part of the 9 programs I wish to analyse. My urlencoded query looks like:

```
My_Base_URL/rest-1.v1/Data/Story?sel=Name,Scope.ID,Scope.Name,Status,AssetState,Custom_AcceptanceCriteria,Scope.ScopeLabels.Name&where=Status.Name='In+Progress';Scope.ParentMeAndUp='Scope:16484';AssetState='64'&with=Scope.ScopeLabels.Name='P-2013-Q4-DPT%2CP-2013-Q4-Engineering+Services+Council%2CP-2013-Q4-FamilySearch+Council%2CP-2013-Q4-Partner+Council%2CP-2013-Q4-RecordsCouncil%2CP-2013-Q4-SearchProductCouncil%2CP-2013-Q4-Standards+and+Authorities+Council%2CP-2013-Q4-TempleCouncil%2CP-2013-Q4-TreeCouncil'
```

The various Scope.ScopeLabels.Names are the 9 I'm trying to limit the results to.

Does anyone see what I need to do differently?
Where is the best documentation for this type of question?
(BTW, the %2C is a urlencoded comma just so you don't have to look that up.

Comment: I may have seen my problem. The following may be the correct query: MyBaseURL/rest-1.v1/Data/Story?sel=Name,Scope.ID,Scope.Name,Status,AssetState,Custom_AcceptanceCriteria,Scope.ScopeLabels.Name&where=Status.Name='In+Progress';Scope.ParentMeAndUp='Scope:16484';AssetState='64';Scope.ScopeLabels.Name=$program&with=$program='P-2013-Q4-DPT%2CP-2013-Q4-Engineering+Services+Council%2CP-2013-Q4-FamilySearch+Council%2CP-2013-Q4-Partner+Council%2CP-2013-Q4-RecordsCouncil%2CP-2013-Q4-SearchProductCouncil%2CP-2013-Q4-Standards+and+Authorities+Council%2CP-2013-Q4-TempleCouncil%2CP-2013-Q4-TreeCouncil'

Answer (score 0):

The last commented attempt did resolve my problem. This coding was done in PHP for those wondering about the syntax.